# Having trouble understanding what files to include to make PHPUnit work properly

Tags: php, unit-testing

I'm trying to get started with unit testing and PHPUnit.  [I see code here that indicates the way to get started is to include 'PHPUnit/Framework.php' and then create a test case that extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html)

It looks like that's no longer the way to include PHPUnit but the [new docs](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.examples.StackTest.php) don't explain what files needed to be included to make PHPUnit work.

What am I missing? When I include 'Framework.php' an error is triggered that tells me no to include that file any longer. 'Autoloader.php' does not work either. When I include files such as 'TestSuiteLoader.php' and others I'll inevitably run into an error that tells me another needed file is missing. I doubt I'm supposed to manually include dozens of files but the docs aren't clear on what I should include yet.

Comment: Your link to the "new docs" points to the 3.5 version, is this normal? And your first link points to an example in the 3.4 version BTW.

Comment: @greg0ire I am using version 3.6 now and the manual for 3.6 and 3.5 are the same on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the phpunit library in your `php.ini's` `include_path` rather including them manually.

My include path is `include_path = ".;C:\wamp\library\phpunit";`

Comment: I installed PHPUnit using PEAR as I do with lots of other packages. I'll try your suggestion though. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying. I think you've pointed out what I was missing.